# javascript event missing after html reset

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a situation where at one point the html contents of a div are changed to something else, and then are changed back. Some of jquery ui controls are misbehaving. I've reduced the problem to the following snippet, which basically shows that the event handler associated with the button doesn't fire anymore. I am assuming that these were garbage collected at some point when they were gone. So my question is -

**How do I prevent event handlers from being garbage collected when they are missing from the DOM**?

I understand that I could just reassign the `click()` function, but since I'm using an external library (jquery ui), i don't really know what's it doing with my controls. I'd just want their events restored as they were before.

```
<div id="container">
    <p>This container has a button, which will forget its click()...</p>
    <input id="testbutton" type="button" value="Click Me!"/>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){ 
        $("#testbutton").click(
            function(){
                alert("Button has been clicked!");
        })
    });
</script>

<div>
    <p>... when this button reseats html</p>
    <input id="actionbutton" type="button" value="Toggle"/>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var toggle = false;
    var html;
    $(function(){ 
        $("#actionbutton").click(
            function(){
                toggle = !toggle;
                if(toggle){
                    html = $("#container").html();
                    $("#container").html("");
                } else  $("#container").html(html);
        })
    });
</script>
```

This [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8S5E4/) demonstrates the problem that I'm having.

Comment: And alternative is to not overwrite the html in the container, but instead use the detach method to remove it and then add it back to the dom - http://jsfiddle.net/8S5E4/4/. Doesn't seem like this is what you wanted though (based on the comments in the fiddle)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple answer: use `.live`

```
$(function(){ 
    $("#testbutton").live('click',
        function(){
            alert("Button has been clicked!");
    })
});
```

Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mrchief/8S5E4/1/

**Explanation:** When you alter the DOM, event handlers attached the element are also removed. Using `.live` attaches the event handlers to 'body' (and filters by DOM element) so that it 'lives' even after removing/adding the same DOM element.

You can achieve the same effect using `.delegate` also:

```
$(function(){ 
    $('#container').delegate('#testbutton', 'click',
        function(){
            alert("Button has been clicked!");
    })
});
```

fiddle using `.delegate`: http://jsfiddle.net/mrchief/8S5E4/6/

I would recommend using `.delegate` over `.live` for:

- You can cancel event bubbling. When you use `live`, the event bubbles up all the way to `body` and then your handler gets called, so there is no way to cancel its bubbling. (As of jQuery 1.4, this can be prevented by using a context argument: http://api.jquery.com/live/)
- Since you're attaching to a DOM element specifically, it doesn't get invoked everytime there is a click on any other DOM element on body and hence, is more performant as it has to do less work now.

Here's a great article that beautifully explains the [differences between live, delegate and bind](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/the-difference-between-jquerys-bind-live-and-delegate/) and discusses about the nuances of each approach. Thanks to @andyb for pointing this link out.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a very comprehensive answer! I still have a problem though, because it's not really I who makes the click() events in the first place, it's jquery ui. What I'll do is post another question and present that particular issue there.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery event delegation to the rescue

```
$("#container").delegate('#testbutton', 'click',
    function(){
        alert("Button has been clicked!");
});
```

Note: [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) [is more efficient](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-the-difference-between-live-and-delegate/) than [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: just out of interest: Is the efficiency-issue still the same? The article you posted is over a year old and was written in times of jquery 1.4. Has the jQuery - Team resolved this or should I start using delegate for these cases?

Comment: As of 1.4, live takes a context argument too `$("div.clickme", $("#container")[0]).live("click", function() {
  // Live handler called.
}); `: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: @GNi33, see @Mrchief's answer for some more reasons why delegate is better, also [a more recent article](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/the-difference-between-jquerys-bind-live-and-delegate/) on the difference. That said, I agree that the linked article is old and that the jQuery team might have tightened up `.live()` since 1.4

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because you're binding an event to `#testbutton` which lives inside of `#container` on document ready. When you clear the HTML of `#container` you're also losing that `#testbutton` bound click event. Rather, the element that the click event references no longer exists.

If you want that button event to persist try using `live()` binding or `delegate()` the event from a parent element.

---

**Using [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)**

```
$(function(){ 
    $("#testbutton").live("click", function() {
        alert("Button has been clicked!");
    })
});
```

> Attach a handler to the event for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.

---

**Using [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)**

```
$(function(){ 
    $("#container").delegate("#testbutton", "click", function() {
        alert("Button has been clicked!");
    })
});
```

> Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the selector, now or in the future, based on a specific set of root elements.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function instead of click

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8S5E4/2/)

Answer (score 0):

`live()` is deprecated. Use `on()`, and if necessary, use it at the `document` level:

```
$(function(){ 
    $(document).on("click", "#testbutton", function() {
        alert("Button has been clicked!");
    })
});
```

By using `$(document)`, regenerating `#testbutton` will still have its event handler intact.