# Protect unspecified Javascript event handlers from being garbage collected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, events, dom

Recently I posed a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998534/javascript-event-missing-after-html-reset), asking why some of my javascript code was misbehaving. However, the accepted answer didn't fully solve my problem, so here I am once again.

### Problem Description

- I have a `<div>` which has a collection of radio buttons in it.
- I use jquery ui to style that collection with a `buttonset()`. It looks resonably pretty.
- Then I empty the `<div>` with jquery by doing something to the effect of `$("#mydiv").html("")`
- Then I once again restore *exact* contents that were removed.
- Finally the buttonset is no longer working properly, because its events got unhinged in the process.

So my question is **how to protect such bound events from being garbage collected, when I temporarily tinker with the DOM?**

**NB!** I can't do `display:none` to hide the `<div>` instead, because the whole business with deleting html content and restoring it later is handled by an unnamed jquery plugin. Nor can I call `buttonset()` again, because a) the graphic style gets messed up, and b) there are other controls in my real problem that don't have this handy functionality. So what I really need is some way to protect all those handlers while the elements which behavior they are supposed to govern are temporarily missing from the DOM.

### Sample Code

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="buttonset">
        <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="option" />
        <label for="radio1">X</label>
        <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="option" />
        <label for="radio2">Y</label>
        <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="option" />
        <label for="radio3">Z</label>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="control">
    <input id="toggle" type="checkbox"/>
    <label for="toggle">Toggle</label>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function(){
    $("#buttonset").buttonset();  
    $("#toggle").click(
        function(){
            if($(this).is(":checked"))
            {
                backup = $("#container").html();
                $("#container").html("");
            } else $("#container").html(backup);
        }
    )
});
```

**Playable Version**

[See this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TnuSv/1/)

**Solution**

I used the idea in the accepted answer to save html contents before applying `buttonset()`, then reapply `buttonset()` each time as needed on that saved data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

Here's an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrchief/TnuSv/4/) that's pretty close to what your OP is. The basic idea is it `destroys` the `buttonset` to get the original html back

```
$(function() {    

    //Turn the radio buttons into a jquery ui buttonset
    $("#buttonset").buttonset();

    //Use the toggle button to hide/show the #container div.
    //NB! It's not possible to do css display:none instead,
    //due to some other limitations, to wit, I'm using a
    //library that I can not modify.
    $("#toggle").button();

    var backup;      // added this to prevent it from leaking onto global scope.

    $("#toggle").click(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {

            // restore the html back
            $("#buttonset").buttonset("destroy");

            backup = $("#container").html();
            $("#container").html("");
        } 
        else { 
            $("#container").html(backup);
            $("#buttonset").buttonset();
        }

    })
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work, still locks up the controls. Care to demonstrate with a jsfiddle?

Comment: Got a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mrchief/TnuSv/3/). Not sure if this is the ideal though.

Comment: Looks great, I'll review this option within an hour, and accept this answer after some tests!

Comment: Hey, I added another fiddle. The basic idea is it `destroys` the `buttonset` to get the original html back. Updated my answer.

Comment: Mrchief, I used your older idea to backup pre-modified html and just retrofit it with all the options. Thanks!